# ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Very Slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, actionresult

I have a WebAPI web service. I am returning a Json string. The controller returns ActionResult, but I have also tried making it JsonRequest. That doesn't affect the outcome.

Here is the relevant code (keeping in mind that the function prototype just returns ActionResult:

```
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - get campaign data: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), 1));

        // Here is the data we're going to need
        var currentUser = context.Users.Where(n => n.UserID == userId).Single();
        var locations = context.Locations.Where(n => n.CampaignID == campaign.CampaignID && n.Inactive == false);
        var questions = context.Questions.Where(n => n.CampaignID == campaign.CampaignID && n.Inactive == false).Include(n => n.QuestionType).ToList().OrderBy(q=> q.SortOrder);
        var dispositions = context.Dispositions.Where(n => n.CampaignID == campaign.CampaignID).ToList().OrderBy(d=> d.SortOrder);
        var answers = context.Answers.Where(a => a.Inactive == false).Join(locations, answer => answer.LocationID, loc => loc.LocationID, (ans, loc) => ans).ToList();
        var contacts = context.Contacts.Where(c => c.Inactive == false);

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - get campaign data: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), 2));

        var json = new
            {
                success = true,
                data = new
                {
                    User = currentUser.ToModel(),
                    Campaign = campaign.ToModel(),
                    Location = locations.ToList().ToModelsSpecial(answers, contacts),
                    Question = questions.OrderBy(q => q.SortOrder).ToModelsSpecial(),
                    Disposition = dispositions.ToModels(),
                },
                message = (string)null
            };

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - get campaign data: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), 3));
        var response = Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - get campaign data: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), 4));

        return response;
```

You can see I have Debug.WriteLine for debugging that outputs how long it takes so I can track it.

So the problem is that all of the processing including the DB queries only takes about 2 seconds. It gets all the way through this whole thing in that time.

And yet I don't get the result on the client for another 25 seconds. I am using a program like Fiddler to test this. It is all on my local machine, so the internet is not the problem.

The size of the returned Json string is 800k. Since this is all local I would not expect that to take 25 seconds.

I am running the site in IIS8 on Windows 8.

Can someone tell me what is taking so long for the ActionResult to get back to the client?

Comment: who is consuming this call - jquery ajax call or some other client?

Comment: I would wonder how the data is rendered.  Repeatedly adding thousands of rows to an html table could easily slow a browser down to a craw if that table is attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I could boost the speed of my Json function only when returned a String instead of JsonResult. I don't now why but it was much faster. Maybe because it is less conversions. I am using mvc 5, tried with an old version but it didn't allow to return string only the JsonResult.

```
 public  String   GetBooks()
    {


        var myBooks = db.Books();

        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();


        return (jsonSerializer.Serialize(myBooks));


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this post.  I believe you are having the same issue, and the fix was just replacing the plugin:

[Struts2+jsonplugin: response takes a long time to display in browser from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478012/struts2jsonplugin-response-takes-a-long-time-to-display-in-browser-from-remote)

Comment: Thank you for response.I took a look at that and I don't think it is the same thing.

Comment: After looking further into this, Fiddler is going to cause more overhead while debugging the code.  If no issues exist, try turning off debug in script and then run it with without using fiddler.  This should give you a better understanding as to if the debug is causing the increased timeframe.

Comment: Keep in mind that anytime you debug code, the process will cause a massive amount of overhead on a system and this could cause the code to be scanned/executed more than once.  Let me know if you still have issues when running it outside of debug/fiddler.  But from what I can see at this point, it is just an issue with overhead.

Comment: I get the same result when not debugging

Comment: down voting since this question is regarding asp.net mvc, and the linked ticket is for a java jar